# What's wrong with my interpolation (paperclip)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

```
  Paperclip.interpolates :normalized_file_name do |attachment, style|
    attachment.instance.normalized_file_name
  end

  has_attached_file :avatar,
  :path        => ':rails_root/public/system/posts/:normalized_file_name-:style.:extension',
  :default_url => '/images/missing_:style.png',
  :url         => '/system/posts/:normalized_file_name-:style.:extension',
  :styles      => {
    :micro     => ['600x300'],
    :preview   => ['200x']
  }
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

  # normalized file name for paperclip (avatar)

  def normalized_file_name
    extension = File.extname(avatar_file_name).downcase
    "#{self.id}-#{self.title.parameterize}"
  end


  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged

  def normalize_friendly_id(input)
    input.to_s.to_slug.normalize(transliterations: :russian).to_s
  end
```

This is the piece of my model, and it works fine when I request certain image (e.g. image_tag post.avatar.url(:micro) for instance) and returns the file name according to the model described here..

BUT! If I go to the /public/system/posts/ I can see the origin file names instead of my interpolation (those files I selected from my computer when adding). This is not a big deal, but I am not happy to have non-english characters in my server or S3 bucket, I am afraid some day it may cause issues on fetching those pictures (IMHO).

**Can someone tell what exactly this interpolation does for my images from paperclip (rails gem)? Thank you!**

Comment: sorry, i don't understand what you are asking for

Comment: Ok, what do you use for the uploaded image renaming? I don't like to keep original names on the server / storage, I want those file names reflect what they stand for. The question is about file naming..